# Django: Questions About Using Solr and Haystack

Tags: python, django, solr, installation, schema

So I did pip install django-haystack or whatever the command was in my project virtualenv folder, and I also have solr installed, but now i'm slightly confused as to what to do.

I keep getting an error saying that the solr backend requires the installation of pysolr? and i'm confused as to where I run this command? "./manage.py build_solr_schema"

i've been trying to refer to the haystack guide but it is a little bit vague. Help me please!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have **Solr 4.10.4** and you use the **example** directory which contains a ready to use Solr configuration.

To install `haystack` if you're using a virtualenv you activate it first and then run

```
pip install django-haystack
```

and to use the **Solr** backend, you also need to install the `pysolr` module in your virtualenv

```
pip install pysolr
```

Than you have to add haystack to your `INSTALLED_APPS` in **settings.py** file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'haystack',
)
```

And you have to set - in your **settings.py** ifle - the search engine backend for haystack to use:

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
    'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/the_core_you_created'
   },
}
```

`the_core_you_created` is the [Solr core](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Solr+Cores+and+solr.xml) you've created for your app.

Now in order to build a search schema you have to register the models you want to store in the serach engine, so you have to create [`SearchIndexes`](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.1/tutorial.html#creating-searchindexes).
Once you've created search indexes you can build the search schema, run:

```
python manage.py build_solr_schema
```

and copy the result in `solr/the_core_you_created/conf/schema.xml`

Now you have to rebuild the index:

```
python manage.py rebuild_index
```

then create a search view and a search template.

You can find the detailed steps in haystack [docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.1/tutorial.html#getting-started-with-haystack) and - more concise - in [Django by example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00YSIL51S) book.